# How to pass access key as an HTTP header using curl in php

Tags: php, api, rest

How can i send a CURL request mentioned below in PHP? What functions i will use in php?

```
$ curl -H 'X-Sifter-Token: 343b1b831066a40e308e0af92e0f06f0' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \ 
'http://example.sifterapp.com/api/projects'
```

I have tried this code.. but its not working.. 
Please do the needful

```
$curlString = "";

$curlString .= "-H \"X-Sifter-Token: 343b1b831066a40e308e0af92e0f06f0\" \";

$curlString .= "-H \"Accept: application/json\" \";

$url="http://example.sifterapp.com/api/projects";


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlString);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
} else {
// Show me the result
var_dump($data);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not use correctly `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. From the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

> CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER    An **array** of HTTP header fields to set, in the
>   format `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`

So you would need:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Sifter-Token: 343b1b831066a40e308e0af92e0f06f0',
        'Accept: application/json',
  ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It completed the CURL request. But i am getting '301 Moved permanently' message. When i used var_dump($response),i got string(184). What all other php CURL function i need to use to complete this request. I am doing this for the first time.

Comment: HTTP 301 might mean that your request is *slightly* off, e.g. you asked for `projects` instead of `projects/`. You can check this by having cURL output all the headers. Fixing the request is more performant; but you can probably have cURL automatically retry with the option to follow redirects (see the setopt man page).